# List comparing with itself

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio, lambda

I'm new to LINQ and Lambda expressions, so i would like to know how to work with my example.

I have the classes:

```
public class Map
{
    public string SourceName { get; set; }
    public string DestinationName { get; set; }
    public List<Assignment> AssignmentList { get; set; }

    public Map()
    {
        AssignmentList = new List<Assignment>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Assignment
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string SourceName { get; set; }
    public string DestinationName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Mandatory { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }

    public void EmptyAssignment()
    {
        Source = "";
        Destination = "";
        SourceName = "";
        DestinationName = "";
        Description = "";
        Mandatory = "False";
        Error = "False";
    }
}
```

Now, I want to check if any assignment.Destination in one Map is equal to an assignment.Source in **any other Map** on the list. All this is in the same list. I have no idea how to compare with itself in an efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

If comparison should be case-sensitive:

```
 map.AssignmentList.Any(a => a.Source == a.Destination)
```

Comment: Hello, I forgot to write a detail. The assignment.Destination is in one Map and assignment.Source in another Map. Sorry for forgetting that.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Map map1 = new Map();
Map map2 = new Map();

var listExists = from d in map1.AssignmentList
join i in map2.AssignmentList
   on d.Source equals i.DestinationName
select d

   if(listExists.Count > 0)
   {
     //is equals
   }
```

Comment: Hello, I forgot to write a detail. The assignment.Destination is in one Map and assignment.Source in another Map. Sorry for forgetting that.

Answer (score 1):

If comparision is case-insensitive use this:

```
 map.AssignmentList.Any(a => a.Source.Equals(a.Destination, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

and for case sensitive comparision:

```
map.AssignmentList.Any(a => a.Source.Equals(a.Destination));
```

Comment: Hello, I forgot to write a detail. The assignment.Destination is in one Map and assignment.Source in another Map. Sorry for forgetting that.